# matching string using index in java

Tags: java, string, performance, indexing

I have two list of string. the first is a list of names (6MB) and the second is a list of sentences (around three millions sentences). 
I want to look for each name through the sentences. It takes days.
I am using pattern matching and also check for regular expression, since the sentences and names are generated by users and uncertain.
how can I do it faster?

Comment: a proper database would probably be faster.

Comment: i have everything in database. i do not know how to use indexing for searching and matching strings. A source to read can help me as well.

Comment: Than create a query that does the job. It should pretty much be faster than doing everything in java.

Comment: You could try hashing the names and then instead of pattern match try to look if a hash exists for every word.

Comment: @KevinEsche the sentence, is not really a sentence. it's all textual information of a record in DB. The name in name list is not exactly within the text, since texts are generated by users and they are not exactly the same. Can you refer me to a reference that I can understand what you mean?

Comment: @Jhonny007 thanks you.
you mean put the sentences in hash table?
sorry I am not an expert, could you guide me to an example?

Answer (score 1):

Store the list of names in a data structure which provides fast lookup (like Hash Table, BST etc.). Java provides libraries for many of them.

Now traverse through the list of sentences and lookup for each token in created names data structure. It will save the time of traversing through list of names each time. Still it's going to take time on single thread but can be easily parallelized.

You can create multiple threads (as per your computational resources) doing the same task but start reading file of sentences from different location.

For more sophisticated parallelization I suggest to use framework like [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) which does computation in-memory and makes task easily scale to any number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/).
Once the data is loaded in it, It can give you an answer within minutes.  It supports SQL-like syntax and regular expressions in predicates.  So you load the sentences into it and can issue queries with the words in where-clause.

Best of all - as with all cloud services, it requires no DB admin skills and no maintenance chores whatsoever. Of course, you need to pay for all that goodness.

I've used the tool to search 300M records with multiple text columns with regular expression and got an answer usually under a minute.

One important caveat to note: this database support no update of the data (no update or delete of records). It is ideal for data that is static - log files, historical records etc.  Another important caveat is of course that the data is in the cloud and not under your control.

Comment: I am not allowed to put my data in the cloud!

Comment: that's a shame. this product is perfect fit for your requirements